# For loop with IF statement C programming

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

```
char userChoice;

printf("Choose how you would like to search.\nEnter A to display all players information.\
            \nEnter N to search a player based on name.\nEnter J to search a player based on jersey number.\
            \nEnter P to search a player based on position.\nEnter your choice: ");
scanf("%c", &userChoice);

do
{
    if (userChoice == 'A' || userChoice == 'a')
    {
        for (index = 0; index < count; index = index + 1)
        {
            displayPlayers(&players[index]);
        }
    }

    if (userChoice == 'J' || userChoice == 'j')
    {
        int jerseyNumber;

        printf("\nEnter jersey number for the player: ");
        scanf("%i", &jerseyNumber);

        for (index = 0; index <= MAX_PLAYERS; index++)
        {
            if (jerseyNumber == players[index].jerseyNumber)
            {
                // If the condition is met the singleDisplay function is called.
                // Containing the array of struct
                singleDisplay(&players[index]);

            }
        }
    }
    if (userChoice == 'N' || userChoice == 'n')
    {
        char playerName[LEN_NAME + 1];

        printf("\nEnter name for the player: ");
        scanf("%s", playerName);

        for (index = 0; index <= MAX_PLAYERS; index++)
        {
            if (strcmp(playerName, players[index].firstName) == 0)
            {
                singleDisplay(&players[index]);

            }
        }
    }
```

Most of this code is just for context,the problem I am having is not being able to make an else statement that outputs a message to user that jersey they entered was not found. The problem is the else statements is inside the loop and will print its message no matter what multiple times, while it is comparing all numbers in array.

Comment: You should look up the `switch` statement in C. It would work well here.

Comment: `for(index=0; index<MAX_PLAYERS; index++) {
                if(jerseyNumber == players[index].jerseyNumber)  {
                    singleDisplay(&players[index]); break/* or set Foundflag */;
                }
            } if(index == MAX_PLAYERS){ printf("Not found!\n");`

Comment: There are no "else statements" there. read your question again.

Comment: I took out else statement since it didn't work properly.

Comment: Not sure how that would work when switch statement only takes 1 variable at a time.Blue idk how that would work MAX_PLAYERS is defined as 26 since that is amount of jerseys

Comment: Including equal signs(`<=`) If you start from `0`, the actual number of players will be `MAX_PLAYERS + 1`, right?

Answer (score 2):

The only relevant part of the code you posted is this:

```
    for (index = 0; index <= MAX_PLAYERS; index++)
    {
        if (jerseyNumber == players[index].jerseyNumber)
        {
            singleDisplay(&players[index]);
        }
    }
```

And the only relevant part of your question is this:

> an else statement that outputs a message to user that jersey they entered was not found. The problem is the else statements is inside the loop and will print its message no matter what multiple times, while it is comparing all numbers in array.

OK, so that's clear.  You must have tried code like this (but failed to show it to us):

```
    for (index = 0; index <= MAX_PLAYERS; index++)
    {
        if (jerseyNumber == players[index].jerseyNumber)
        {
            singleDisplay(&players[index]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("no match for jersey number\n");
        }
    }
```

Of course the error message will be printed `MAX_PLAYERS` times, or maybe `MAX_PLAYERS - 1` times if it was found.  So you need to modify your code to explicitly avoid this:

```
    int found = 0;
    for (index = 0; index <= MAX_PLAYERS; index++)
    {
        if (jerseyNumber == players[index].jerseyNumber)
        {
            singleDisplay(&players[index]);
            found++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        printf("no match for jersey number\n");
    }
```

The `break` there is optional, but is good form because it avoids checking more numbers once you've already found a match.  That is, unless you want to support having multiple players with the same jersey number, in which case remove the `break`.